# How to make difference between Opera and Opera Mini in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, opera, opera-mini

Some of the features from my website don't work on Opera Mini, but they work on Opera.
Is there a way to tell difference between these two browsers in JavaScript, so that I could prevent people from accessing certain pages of my website?

I've tried window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Opera Mini/') but it also works for Opera...
Object.prototype.toString.call(window.operamini) === "[object OperaMini]" doesn't work at all

Comment: `var isOperaMini = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Opera Mini') > -1);` is returning true for Opera? How come?

Comment: that pieces of code returns false for both...
window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Opera Mini/') returns true for both

Comment: of course it returns true, you need to compare with -1

Comment: yeah, that was my mistake. it returns false in that case too...

Comment: You mean even for Opera?

Comment: I believe Opera Mini has unique object so if you can detect the object then the browser is Opera Mini: `var isOperaMini = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.operamini) === "[object OperaMini]"`

Comment: imudin07: even for Opera
Jon: I've told it in question, that also doesn't work (returns false in both opera and opera mini)

Comment: try this `var isOperaMini = !!(Object.prototype.toString.call(window.operamini) === "[object OperaMini]" || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Opera Mini') > -1) || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('OperaMini') > -1) || !!window['operamini']);`

Comment: still false... I'm examining useragent string, they are different in two points (beside version number): U; and wv

Answer (score 0):

Opera Mini use 3 modes for major platforms(iOS, Android):

1. Default mode - without compression
2. High saving mode - compress content only (images, video and etc)
3. Extreme mode - full compression using `OBLM`

Only extreme mode is real Opera Mini, in other cases Opera Mini uses default browser engine, but with a additional letters `OPR/` in user agent string.

So you just need to check `window.operamini` for extreme mode and `OPR/` in user agent string for other modes.

```
const isOperaMini = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('OPR/') !== -1;
const isOperaMiniExtreme = isOperaMini && !!window.operamini;
```

That's all. This is the only way.

Comment: No, it is not the only way. See: https://bitsofco.de/better-detection-and-analytics-for-opera-browsers/